# is there a way to represent strings that can avoid human typing errors in tsql? similar to object oriented language such as java or swift?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In swift, java and many other language, having to type names of objects as strings can be the source of many error because it is very easy to misspell strings, especially if it is long. So to avoid this problem, constant variables can be created and is assigned to the string, and we can then use the constant variable where ever the string is needed.

I have recently started learning microsoft sql server and I was just wondering if there is a way, in sql server, to represent strings that can avoid human typing errors?

Comment: Is it called `orm` ...

Comment: i'm sorry, Im not exactly sure, due to my lack of experience...

Comment: `orm` maps data into java entities , then use java entities to generate sqls , using java to avoid typing errors , isn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very high level answer to your question only.

For t-SQL code you can declare variables at the start of the code block and then use those throughout the code, with some stipulations. There are no actual constants, as we see in vb.net for example (CONST myValue AS Int32), but there are techniques you can use to provide the same functionality (table-based, function-based, ect.)

For t-sql, you declare the variable and its datatype up front:
For Example, we might wish to reference a data value name throughout the code, thus you could use :

DECLARE @MyValue as INT
SELECT cOL1, cOL2
FROM MyTable
WHERE Col3 = @MyValue

The same can be said for Stored Procedures and Functions, where you pass parameters:
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.stMySProc
    @MyValue INT = NULL
AS 
  ......

Then the code can use @MyValue, together with other declared variables, within the code block.

There are a number of rules that apply, one is the scope of that variable. The following will work:

DECLARE @MyValue as INT
SELECT cOL1, cOL2
FROM MyTable
WHERE Col3 = @MyValue
GO

but the following will fail

DECLARE @MyValue as INT
GO
SELECT cOL1, cOL2
FROM MyTable
WHERE Col3 = @MyValue

Simply because the GO statement splits the code into separate batches, and variables are effectively thrown away at that point.

Secondly, you cannot declare the same variable name twice in the same code block, even if it has a different data type, and as t-sql is not case sensitive, even if different case is used!

Thus, this will error:

DECLARE
@MyValue as INT

DECLARE
@myvalue as varchar(50)

and this will be OK

DECLARE
@MyValue as INT
GO
DECLARE
@myvalue as varchar(50)

Hope this provides just a taste of what you are seeking.